# SecureCRT Does not Even Offer to Import Host Key

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

I am troubleshooting an SSH connection between a Windows client running SecureCRT v8.1.4 and an Oracle Linux 9 server running OpenSSH v8.7. The client connects but then drops the connection immediately telling me:

> The client has disconnected from the server.  Reason:
> The server's host key failed to verify.  This could mean that the server you are connected to is impersonating the server it claims to be. A connection could not be established.

It doesn't even offer to accept the key.

This behavior seems to happen on all the OL9 servers. The client can connect fine to Oracle Linux 8 servers which are running OpenSSH v8.0.

According to the following debug information pulled from the sshd log it doesn't really look like a problem with the host key but something after that -- perhaps the KEX negotiation. I tried turning the crypto-policy from DEFAULT to LEGACY with no improvement. My searches turn up a lot of information on how to make SecureCRT and OpenSSH work together but nothing so far that helps with this particular error.

The SecureCRT in question is an older version which will probably not be upgraded. User does have a workaround.

Debug log

```
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44631]: debug3: fd 4 is not O_NONBLOCK
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44631]: debug1: Forked child 44647.
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: oom_adjust_restore
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: rexec start in 4 out 4 newsock 4 pipe 6 sock 7
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44631]: debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 7 config len 3642
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44631]: debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44631]: debug3: send_rexec_state: done
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: Connection from 10.222.217.253 port 28442 on 10.222.75.42 port 22 rdomain ""
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.7
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SecureCRT_8.1.4 (x64 build 1443)
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: compat_banner: no match: SecureCRT_8.1.4 (x64 build 1443)
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: ssh_sandbox_init: preparing seccomp filter sandbox
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: Network child is on pid 44648
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: preauth child monitor started
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: SELinux support enabled [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: ssh_selinux_change_context: setting context from 'system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023' to 'system_u:system_r:sshd_net_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023' [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: privsep user:group 74:74 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: setting PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: attaching seccomp filter program [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 42 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 42
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 43
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect: entering, type 43 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive: entering [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: KEX algorithms: gss-group14-sha256-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group16-sha512-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-nistp256-sha256-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-curve25519-sha256-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,x509v3-sign-rsa,x509v3-ssh-rsa,x509v3-sign-dss,x509v3-ssh-dss,ssh-dss [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,twofish-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,arcfour [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,twofish-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,arcfour [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,umac-64@openssh.com [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,umac-64@openssh.com [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: compression ctos: none [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: compression stoc: none [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp521 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-512 compression: none [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-512 compression: none [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: kex: ecdh-sha2-nistp521 need=64 dh_need=64 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 120 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect: entering, type 121 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive: entering [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 120
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 121
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: kex: ecdh-sha2-nistp521 need=64 dh_need=64 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 120 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect: entering, type 121 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive: entering [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 120
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 121
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT received [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_sshkey_sign: entering [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 6 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_sshkey_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect: entering, type 7 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive: entering [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
Mar 29 12:03:38 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_answer_sign: entering
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_answer_sign: ssh-rsa (effective: rsa-sha2-256) KEX signature len=532
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 7
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: receive packet: type 1 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: error: Received disconnect from 10.222.217.253 port 28442:9: The server's host key failed to verify.  This could mean that the server you are connected to is impersonating the server it claims to be. A connection could not be established.  [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 122 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect: entering, type 123 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive: entering [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 122
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 123
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: Disconnected from 10.222.217.253 port 28442 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_send: entering, type 124 [preauth]
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 124
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: do_cleanup
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
Mar 29 12:03:39 scasyslog04 sshd[44647]: debug1: Killing privsep child 44648
```